# Which licence do I need to link to when using a resource under CC BY 4.0 Generalitat?

Tags: licensing

I am using this WMS endpoint:

https://terramapas.icv.gva.es/0202_2022CVAL0025?service=wms&request=getcapabilities

The XML source says:

```
<AccessConstraints>CC BY 4.0 Generalitat</AccessConstraints>
```

I know that standard [CC BY 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/) licence requires me to ["provide a link to the license"](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/). What licence do I need to link to when the licence is `CC BY 4.0 Generalitat`?

Answer (score 1):

"Generalitat" refers to "[Generalitat Valenciana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalitat_Valenciana)", which is considered the author here (see [this page](https://icv.gva.es/va/condiciones-de-uso-de-la-geoinformacion-icv)). There's no license called "CC BY 4.0 Generalitat", the field "AccessConstraints" is simply a concatenation of the license name and the author name.

The license here is `CC BY 4.0`, and the link to its full text in English is:

**https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/legalcode** (which is the link you're after).

If for whatever reason you need it, there's also a version of the license summary in the Catalan language: https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/deed.ca